# android-Kind of drop down list

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop down list as it is shown in the image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhTVu.png)

So when it is clicked,I want it to show up like this right under the text.I want to get some source to do this.If you can give any source it will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I tried custom spinner etc. But I found my need anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for ExpandableListView in Android. That gives the same kind of implementation you are looking for.
This would be a good tutorial for that:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/